# How to use a string var like using ui file? (PySide6)

Tags: python, pyside6

**Something else:**

I am using a program that uses PySide6 and ui file.

In fact,there's two questions.

One is non-programming.

I don't know that is it allowed to ask both of them in one question(Please tell me.).

So,I'll just ask the programming question.

**My question:**

Let me explain the title.

When I'm using a ui file,

I'll use:

```
QUiLoader().load(QFile(*File Name*))
```

But,I have to make the program self-starting.

Because of some unknown reason,even though the ui file is exist,py will say:

```
RuntimeError: Unable to open/read ui device
```

(If I run it actively,it can work well)

So I want to copy the xml in the file as a string var.

Such as:

```
ui = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
...
"""
```

I need a way that equivalent to use a ui file to use the var.

Comment: Don't do that.  You are better off giving the loader the correct path.  which is probably relative to the current working directory, or an absolute path will work as well.

Comment: That would be pointless given the reason for which you're doing it (see [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). If the problem is that the script cannot load the file, try to find a solution to solve *that* problem: you don't add a new gas tank to your car when you're out of gas: you look for a gas station. What do you mean by "I have to make the program self-starting"? Are you making an executable from it? If so, did you include the ui file in the executable? Or do you mean that you want do directly run the script without calling python?

Comment: @musicamante OK,I've known my problem now. I've also solved,absolute path works..THANK U SO MUCH

Comment: @LonelyWolf-孤狼 Be aware that using hardcoded absolute paths is rarely a good idea, especially if the relative path *can* be found. For instance, if you know that the ui file is in the same path of the python script (or a directory closely related to it), using the absolute path would be pointless and nonsensical: just access the `__file__` var and get the path dynamically using the `os` or pathlib module.